# How to set AuthenticationFlow and ResponseMode in .Net 6

Tags: openid-connect, .net-6.0, identitymodel, authentication-flows

I migrated my application from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6 and also upgraded the IdentityModel.OidcClient nuget package(currently using 5.2.1 version). But now I don't see the Flow(AuthenticationFlow) and ResponseMode properties in OidcClientOptions class. Could someone please help/guide me on how to set up these properties? Thanks in advance!

Here is the current code:

```
{
    Authority = "https://your-identity-server.com",
    ClientId = "your-client-id",
    ClientSecret = "your-client-secret",
    RedirectUri = "https://your-redirect-uri.com",
    Scope = "openid profile email",
    Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid,
    ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.FormPost
};

var client = new OidcClient(options);
```

I want to set Hybrid authentication flow and FormPost response mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to the maintainers the **HybridFlow** is not supported starting from 4.x https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/325

```
I removed hybrid and form-post in favour of staying closer to the RFC.

The only flow supported now is authorization code with the query response type.
```